# How can I use orgstruct mode in Text mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Org includes [Orgstruct mode](http://orgmode.org/manual/Orgstruct-mode.html), which adds org-like functionality to other minor modes. In the documentation, they suggest that you might want to do this for message or text modes. I do! I adapted their message code to work for `mu4e`, but couldn't adapt it to work for `text-mode`.

They suggest this code:

```
(add-hook 'message-mode-hook 'turn-on-orgstruct)
```

I tried the following versions:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-orgstruct)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'orgstruct-mode)
```

And a version using a `lambda`.

However, all of these prevent Emacs from launching as a daemon. If I run Emacs normally (not as a daemon), it works, but pops an error:

> font-lock-default-unfontify-buffer: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'

I imagine this has something to do with the way `text-mode` relates to other major modes. Can I safely use `orgstruct-mode` in `text-mode`? How?

Comment: You should give us the error message It would probably help us understand what happen. By the way, why don't you use turn-on-orgstruct in text mode?

Comment: I added the error-- fyi, the error comes from trying to use turn-on-orgstruct in text-mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite regress: text-mode runs the hook which turn on orgstruct-mode which calls org-get-local-variables which calls org-mode. But org-mode is a derived mode of outline-mode, which is a derived mode of text-mode, so text-mode-hook is called recursively: boom.

To get around this problem, I switch text-mode entries in `auto-mode-alist` to full org-mode. I only use orgstruct++-mode and orgtbl-mode automatically in messages. Sometimes I turn on orgtbl-mode manually in latex, but that is rare: most of the time, I export to latex from org.